# Help with query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I have following data.

I am trying to get the number of days the project stayed in a particular status. Example below of raw data, I need to be able to get the result shown.

Can I get some pointers on how I can achieve this?

#### Raw data

```
╔══════════════════════════════════╦════════╦════════════╗
║                ID                ║ STATUS ║ ENTRY_DATE ║
╠══════════════════════════════════╬════════╬════════════╣
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ WIH    ║ 9/25/2015  ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ CPL    ║ 9/9/2015   ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ CPL    ║ 7/21/2015  ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ CPL    ║ 7/21/2015  ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ CPL    ║ 7/8/2015   ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ CUR    ║ 6/25/2015  ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ CPL    ║ 6/25/2015  ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ CPL    ║ 6/16/2015  ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ TNJ    ║ 5/26/2015  ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ CPL    ║ 5/15/2015  ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ CPL    ║ 4/22/2015  ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ CUR    ║ 4/16/2015  ║
╚══════════════════════════════════╩════════╩════════════╝
```

#### Expected results

```
╔══════════════════════════════════╦════════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║                ID                ║ STATUS ║ ENTRY_DATE ║ EXIT_DATE ║
╠══════════════════════════════════╬════════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ WIH    ║ 9/25/2015  ║ NULL      ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ CPL    ║ 7/8/2015   ║ 9/25/2015 ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ CUR    ║ 6/25/2015  ║ 7/8/2015  ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ CPL    ║ 6/16/2015  ║ 6/25/2015 ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ TNJ    ║ 5/26/2015  ║ 6/16/2015 ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ CPL    ║ 4/22/2015  ║ 5/26/2015 ║
║ 541c4cfd009784b7ad7b47a552ab7ea2 ║ CUR    ║ 4/16/2015  ║ 4/22/2015 ║
╚══════════════════════════════════╩════════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: How do you determine the order of statuses happening on the same day, like the CLP & CUR on 6/25? Is there some kind of ID or other internal order?

Comment: Same day status means the status was flipped in the middle of the day. I can get the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can group the data using a trick using row number - row number partitioned by status. That will create the same number for rows with the same status for a range of dates. This just takes the rows ordered by entry_date and status, but you might want to do something better for the entries on the same day:

```
select
  ID, status, 
  min(entry_date) as entry_date, 
  nullif (max(exit_date),'99991231') as exit_date
from
(
  select
    *,
    isnull(lead(entry_date) over (partition by id order by entry_date, status),'99991231') as exit_date,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by entry_date, status)
    - row_number() over (partition by id, status order by entry_date) as GRP
  From 
    table1
) X
group by ID, status, GRP
order by id, entry_date desc
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/467f84/2)

Update: Fixed group by id, added handling for null / max exit_date for cases when the newest status has more than one row.

Answer (score 1):

Windowed function `LAG` should give you the answer:

[LAG (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)

This function allows it so you don't have to join to get [current]-nth value

```
SELECT 
    *,
    LAG([ENTRY_DATE], 1, NULL) OVER (
        PARTITION BY [ID], [STATE], [ENTRY_DATE] 
        ORDER BY [ENTRY_DATE]) AS EXIT_DATE
FROM table;
```